# HyperV is not available on Home editions

Tags: windows, docker

Just got message "HyperV is not available on Home editions" when installing Docker 1.12

As checking about [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), I wonder **is it possible to install separate HyperV on Windows 10 Home and latest Docker to be able to use it.**

As I understand "Docker for Windows" is now new recommended way to get started with Docker on Windows PC.

Comment: The error seems perfectly clear that you aren't allowed to use Hyper-V on Home editions. There is no separate Hyper-V or whatever. I suppose you can reprogram Docker to use some other virtualizer. Go to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using Windows 10 Home and don't want to upgrade, you can use Docker Toolbox instead: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

Answer (score 3):

The next version of Docker for Windows will run on WSL 2 and MS has made an exception for WSL 2, allowing it to use hyper-V even on Home editions of Windows 10.

This means that the answer will be Yes: you can use the full, normal version of Docker on Windows Home.

If you want to do so now you will need to install the [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index) preview (which requires an insiders edition of Windows) band then install the preview of [the new Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/).