# Docker installation issues on Windows 10 Home Edition

Tags: docker

I am facing problem while installing the Docker on my machine. OS is Windows 10 Home Edition. I want to use Splash and that needs Docker.

[image]

Comment: Well, why don't you use docker toolbox as the warning says?

Comment: Upgrade to windows 10 pro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HyperV is not available on Home editions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959116/hyperv-is-not-available-on-home-editions)

Comment: @masterfan i already installed but it is not working also.

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: @masterfan it is showing only blank cmd screen.

Comment: Yes, you can install docker on win 10 home, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387049/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home-can-it-be-done/54387050?noredirect=1#comment100818252_54387050

Comment: There is now an easier way to do this using chocolatey tool, detailed instructions here -> https://medium.com/@remisharoon/the-smartest-way-to-run-docker-on-windows-10-home-441c4dd215d

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Docker Toolbox ( Old Link ):  https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

---

Now You can use Docker Toolbox from here: https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/

Follow these steps to install Docker Toolbox: https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#step-3-verify-your-installation

**or:**

https://docs.bitnami.com/containers/how-to/install-docker-in-windows/

**Tutorial For Virtualization :** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10/windows10_virtualization.htm

Comment: yes i installed this from the link you shared here.

Comment: @MuhammadZiaUrRahman The Steps To Install as mention below link

Comment: i installed it as per instructions but it is giving blank windows in docker terminal!!!

Comment: run as administrator ??

Comment: yes i run as administrator but still blank window is there.

Comment: still same issue. @RïshïKêsh Kümar

Comment: Did you turn on the virtualisation in BIOS(EFI)?

Comment: @AlexKroll how can i do this. that was not in the instruction of docker installation. please guide me thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadZiaUrRahman  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/08/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10/windows10_virtualization.htm ..

Comment: Minor correction. The link for Docker Toolbox is now `https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/`

Comment: @zipzit Thanxz For Sharing Updated Link Of Docker, Actually My Account Its temporarily suspended, So I am unable to Update the Link... 
  So Just Comment from Another Id, The New Link of Docker toolbox is Here :: 
  `https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/`

Comment: There is now an easier way to do this using chocolatey tool, detailed instructions here -> https://medium.com/@remisharoon/the-smartest-way-to-run-docker-on-windows-10-home-441c4dd215d

Answer (score 3):

First, check that your PC supports Hyper-V and you have Hyper-V enabled in BIOS. Windows Home does not allows to install some features/packages in GUI, but it's possible to add them from command line.

Make a file `hyperv.bat` file and run is at Administrator:

```
@rem Install Hyper-V on Windows Home
pushd "%~dp0"
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\*Hyper-V*.mum >hyper-v.txt
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . hyper-v.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"
del hyper-v.txt
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All /LimitAccess /ALL
pause
```

Reboot computer after that. Then you need to trick the Docker installer to think you have Windows Pro: change your registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` and change `EditionID` from `Core` to `Professional`.

Instal Docker for Windows, change the registry back. And that's all.

See also https://xmedeko.blogspot.com/2019/04/running-docker-on-windows-10-home.html

Comment: There is now an easier way to do this using chocolatey tool, detailed instructions here -> https://medium.com/@remisharoon/the-smartest-way-to-run-docker-on-windows-10-home-441c4dd215d

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable from BIOS
2. CPU virtualization is allowed only for 1 tool on Windows 10 Home. So, remove any other virtualization tool. 
      So, uncheck even Windows Hypervisor Platform in 'Turn Windows features on and off'
3. Disable Credential Guard as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage
   This doesn't happens when the credential helper is run in 'Administrative mode', reason being that running scripts is disabled, we need to enable it
       So, as per https://winaero.com/blog/change-powershell-execution-policy-windows-10/
       Open 'Command Prompt' in 'Administrator' mode and type -

   ```
   cd C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File E:\software\dgreadiness_v3.6\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot
   ```

   After this, the system reboots and credential guard is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install Docker on Windows 10 home edition by installing legacy Docker software called Docker toolbox and enabling the virtualization in my systems BIOS. Check this to follow the procedure: [Installing Docker on Windows 10 home successfully](https://thewebspark.com/2019/04/04/how-to-install-docker-on-windows-10-home-edition-solved/)
[How to enable virtualization in your systems](https://thewebspark.com/2019/04/02/how-to-enable-virtualization-in-bios-of-windows-10-home-hp-systems-solved/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go the Hyper-V way you can use Docker with WSL2(Windows Subsystem for Linux) for Windows 10 Home.

1. Go to Settings -> Update&Security -> Windows Insider Program and enroll for the 'Slow' track of windows insider.
2. Enable WSL from instructions given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
3. Upgrade to WSL2 from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel
4. Download this version of Docker which supports WSL2 during installation itself :
      https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe
5. Check the boxes to use WSL2 instead of Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the latest Windows 20H1 update you can install Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Home.

c.f. https://www.codingnagger.com/2020/06/20/install-docker-desktop-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Windows is available for

1. Windows 10 64-bit professional and
2. BIOS-enable virtualization

To run Docker, your machine must have a 64-bit operating system running Windows 7 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

The home edition of Win 10 does not support virtualization but you can enable.

1. Click on the link https://www.itechtics.com/?dl_id=80 and download the batch file that enables the Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home.
2. Next, right-click on the batch file and select “Run as Administrator“. Keep in mind, you have to be connected to the Internet to enable this feature!
3. Once the installation is complete, RESTART your computer!
4. A Windows Features window will open up. Now, scroll down and enable all the checkboxes under Hyper-V, and hit the OK button.
5. Open the Start menu and search for “Hyper-V”. If Hyper-V is not showing up in the search results, then open the Run dialog using the Win+R key combo. Now, enter virtmgmt.msc and hit Enter.
6. The Hyper-V Manager window should now appear.

Now that Hyper-V is enabled, you may start creating your first virtual machine (VM).