# Docker for windows 10

Tags: windows, docker

I tried installing Docker for Windows 10. Here's the error that I get:

> Unable to stop: The running command stopped because the preference
>   variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop:
>   The specified module 'Hyper-V' was not loaded because no valid module
>   file was found in any module directory. at , :
>   line 79 at Docker.Backend.HyperV.RunScript(String action, Dictionary`2
>   parameters) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV.cs:line
>   177 at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStop() in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line
>   280 at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings)
>   in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line
>   122 at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[]
>   parameters) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line
>   47 at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action,
>   Object[] parameters) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line
>   145

Any inputs on how to fix this error?

Comment: It is poissible to install docker on win 10 Home, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387049/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home-can-it-be-done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the host is Windows 10 Home edition. If it is, go download and install [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox) for Windows, which includes up-to-date Docker and some environment components. Follow the [manual](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) to ensure it works.

Docker for Windows relies on native Hyper-V to create virtual machine. But Win 10 Home edition does not have it. Usually Docker installer [reports this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406422/docker-installation-issues-on-windows-10-home-edition) at installation. Such environment detection could be done at earlier stage of installation, instead of an error at launch.

Comment: i did that. But all I get is a command-line interface with 1970s graphic of a whale and a Mingw64 command set . . .  I want my modern GUI - just like I had in the previous edition of Docker.

Comment: Got it now. Have to use Kitematic to access the GUI, open one's account and select image. Today I mourn not having got Win Pro with my new machine for maybe €50 extra - versus €150 for buying it now.